# No keyword with name 'adm@yourstore.com' found. in robot framework. When i try to run the this script on pycharm, i'm getting this error message

Tags: python, pycharm, robotframework

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary
Resource    ../Resources/LoginError.robot
Suite Setup    Open my browser
Suite Teardown    Close my browser
Test Template

*** Test Cases ***    U_name    pwd

Wrong Username and Wrong Password    adm@yourstore.com    123
Wrong Username and Right password    adm@yourstore.com    admin
Right Username and Wrong Password    admin@yourstore.com    123
Right Username and Empty Password    admin@yourstore.com    ${EMPTY}
Wrong Username and Empty Password    adm@yourstore.com    ${EMPTY}

*** Keywords ***

Invalid Login
        [Arguments]    ${Username}    ${Password}
        Input the Username    ${Username}
        Input the Password    ${Password}
        Click on login
        Verify Presence of error message
```

No keyword with name 'adm@yourstore.com' found. in robot framework. When i try to run the this script on pycharm, i'm getting this error message     .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about you pass `Invalid Login` to the **Test Template** ?

```
*** Settings ***
Library     SeleniumLibrary
Resource    ../Resources/LoginError.robot
Suite Setup    Open my browser
Suite Teardown    Close my browser
Test Template     Invalid Login

*** Test Cases ***    U_name    pwd
(...)
```

Comment: You were correct...Thanks a lot,.. _/\_